# Looping through dictionaries within a list and add row to DataFrame

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a list of items I am trying to unpack from a dictionary which is nested inside another list.

I then want to add the row to a DataFrame.

```
headers = ['minutesPlayed', 'goals', 'goalsAssist', 'shotsOnTarget',
           'shotsOffTarget', 'shotsBlocked', 'hitWoodwork', 'totalContest', 
           'penaltyMiss', 'penaltyWon', 'bigChanceMissed']
```

[Python Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8J56.png)

The code I have tried is:

```
rows = []
for groups in data['groups']:
    row = []

    #Summary
    row.append(groups['minutesPlayed'])
    row.append(groups['goals'])
    row.append(groups['goalAssist'])

    #Attack
    row.append(groups['shotsOnTarget'])
    row.append(groups['shotsOffTarget'])
    row.append(groups['shotsBlocked'])
    row.append(groups['hitWoodwork'])
    row.append(groups['totalContest'])
    row.append(groups['penaltyMiss'])
    row.append(groups['penaltyWon'])
    row.append(groups['bigChanceMissed'])
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
```

However I receive the error:

```
KeyError: 'shotsOnTarget'
```

It doesn't allow me to iterate over the second element within the groups list.

Any tips?

***EDIT added print of data[group]:***

```
print(data['groups'])
[{'minutesPlayed': "89'", 'goals': '0', 'goalAssist': '1', 'statisticsItems': [{'minutesPlayed': 'Minutes played'}, {'goals': 'Goals'}, {'goalAssist': 'Assists'}], 'groupName': 'Summary'}, {'shotsOnTarget': '0', 'shotsOffTarget': '0', 'shotsBlocked': '1', 'hitWoodwork': '0', 'totalContest': '1 (0)', 'goals': '0', 'goalAssist': '1', 'penaltyMiss': '0', 'penaltyWon': '0', 'bigChanceMissed': '0', 'statisticsItems': [{'shotsOnTarget': 'Shots on target'}, {'shotsOffTarget': 'Shots off target'}, {'shotsBlocked': 'Shots blocked'}, {'totalContest': 'Dribble attempts (succ.)'}], 'groupName': 'Attack'}, {'touches': 55, 'accuratePass': '26 (70.3%)', 'keyPass': '1', 'totalCross': '0 (0)', 'totalLongBalls': '2 (0)', 'bigChanceCreated': '0', 'statisticsItems': [{'touches': 'Touches'}, {'accuratePass': 'Passes (acc.)'}, {'keyPass': 'Key passes'}, {'totalCross': 'Crosses (acc.)'}, {'totalLongBalls': 'Long balls (acc.)'}], 'groupName': 'Passing'}, {'possessionLost': '26', 'groundDuels': '9 (0)', 'aerialDuels': '3 (1)', 'wasFouled': '0', 'fouls': '2', 'offsides': '0', 'statisticsItems': [{'groundDuels': 'Ground duels (won)'}, {'aerialDuels': 'Aerial duels (won)'}, {'possessionLost': 'Possession lost'}, {'fouls': 'Fouls'}, {'wasFouled': 'Was fouled'}], 'groupName': 'Other'}, {'totalClearance': '0', 'clearanceOffLine': '0', 'blockedScoringAttempt': '0', 'interceptionWon': '0', 'totalTackle': '0', 'challengeLost': '1', 'lastManTackle': '0', 'errorLeadToShot': '0', 'errorLeadToGoal': '0', 'ownGoals': '0', 'penaltyConceded': '0', 'statisticsItems': [{'totalClearance': 'Clearances'}, {'blockedScoringAttempt': 'Blocked shots'}, {'interceptionWon': 'Interceptions'}, {'totalTackle': 'Tackles'}, {'challengeLost': 'Dribbled past'}], 'groupName': 'Defence'}]
```

Comment: `'shotsOnTarget'` is the second element which is accessible only in the second iteration of your loop.

Comment: Hi Austin, thanks for the quick reply, how would you access the second iteration within the loop?

Comment: @SunilChavda is there any role of `headers` list?

Comment: @shivank98 yes I am using the headers list for the column names within my DataFrame

Comment: @SunilChavda can you please print the `data['groups']` I am not exactly getting what that is from image

Comment: @shivank98 I have edited the question to add the print of data['groups'] - essentially it is dictionaries contained within a list

Answer (score 1):

Your `data['groups']` is a list. whose elements are dicts now your `minutesPlayed`, `goals` and `goalAssist` is in your first element of the list so they are being called when your `groups`variable from for loop is run but your `shotsOnTarget` and others are in the second element. A nicer way of doing it can be following. you don't need a for loop.

```
#Summary
row.append(data['groups'][0]['minutesPlayed'])
row.append(data['groups'][0]['goals'])
row.append(data['groups'][0]['goalAssist'])

#Attact
row.append(data['groups'][1]['shotsOnTarget'])
# same for others,
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, so this solution partially worked but did not capture all as the elements of the groups could change.

For example, data['groups'][1]['shotsOnTarget'] could change to data['groups'][5]['shotsOnTarget'] - being contained within the 5th element.

I believe this is why I thought looping could have been a good idea